# Loop through the rows of a particular DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

IDE : VS 2008,
Platform : .NET 3.5,

Hi,

Here is my DataTable columns :

ID Note Detail

I want to write sth like this :

```
//below code block is not the right syntax


For each q in dtDataTable.Column("Detail")

    strDetail = Row of Column Detail

 Next
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion and show me a code sample please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
    strDetail = row.Item("Detail")
Next row
```

There's also a shorthand:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtDataTable.Rows
    strDetail = row("Detail")
Next row
```

Note that Microsoft's style guidelines for .Net now specifically recommend against using hungarian type prefixes for variables.  Instead of "strDetail", for example, you should just use "Detail".

FWIW, I'd really like to see support for this (and also the async equivalent) built directly into ADO.Net.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim row As DataRow
For Each row In dtDataTable.Rows
    Dim strDetail As String
    strDetail = row("Detail")
    Console.WriteLine("Processing Detail {0}", strDetail)
Next row
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best way I found:

```
    For Each row As DataRow In your_table.Rows
        For Each cell As String In row.ItemArray
            'do what you want!
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop on the .Rows, and access the column for the row like q("column")

Just:

```
        For Each q In dtDataTable.Rows
            strDetail = q("Detail")
        Next
```

Also make sure to check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(VS.80).aspx) doc for any class you are using + use intellisense