# How to use a function in a web service

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I have a webservice with a function in it. It was in the application and I want to use it but im not sure exactly how it works.

My problems lie with the function header, and the return at the end? not sure what should be there. Basically my webservice must run a stored procudure , the loop through a dataset and the rows the procudure returns should be displayd in a string.

C# help also welcome

Web Service:

Function:

```
' Not sure what must be in header. '
Public Function SelectAuditsFunction(ByVal PTC_ID As Integer, ByVal Message As String) As String

        Dim success As Boolean = False
        Dim lblLinkedAudits As String
        Dim sqlString As String = String.Empty
        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim connString As String = "MyConn"
        Dim cmdGetPol As New SqlCommand("p_GetLinkedProcuduresProtocol")
        cmdGetPol.Parameters.AddWithValue("PTC_ID", PTC_ID)
        cmdGetPol.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdGetPol.Connection = conn


        Dim sqlConnGetLinkedAudits As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnManagement").ConnectionString)
        sqlConnGetLinkedAudits.Open()

        Dim sqlDataAdapGetLinkedAudits As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, sqlConnGetLinkedAudits)
        sqlDataAdapGetLinkedAudits.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim sqlParGetLinkedAudits As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@PTC_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)

        sqlDataAdapGetLinkedAudits.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParGetLinkedAudits)

        Dim dsGetLinkedAudits As New DataSet
        Try
            sqlDataAdapGetLinkedAudits.Fill(dsGetLinkedAudits, "LinkedAudits") '<--- Not sure how to loop through all the items in dataset and set to a string.
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            sqlConnGetLinkedAudits.Close()
            sqlConnGetLinkedAudits.Dispose()
        End Try

        For Each dr As DataRow In dsGetLinkedAudits.Tables(0).Rows
            lblLinkedAudits = (dr("dsProtocols"))
        Next
        'Return Here not sure what to do, At the end the string should be returned! 
        Return lblLinkedAudits.ToString

    End Function
```

Comment: try see about [webmethodattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Do not ignore exceptions. You want to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK first things first:

WebServices must be referenced in the place where you want to call them, you can do anything in the service side and it will do nothing if you don't start the service and reference it in the client

Secondly, to loop on a Dataset it could be like this in this answer

[Loop through datatable rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613539/loop-through-the-rows-of-a-particular-datatable)

Third, it just needs the return of that in string form so you could use a StringBuilder to append accordingly what you need

Finally the header of the function you should have an IServiceFile on the project, in there it should be [OperationContract] directly above your function, that way the service is letting know that that function can be called

Comment: If you need an example of the StringBuilder or referencing, just let me know. The dataset loop I think it's pretty straightforward in the link