# 'For each' loop based in SQL select statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to figure out how to perform a 'For Each' loop for each distinct value returned from an SQL query.

Here is my pseudo code.

```
connection.ConnectionString = "server=***01\SQLEXPRESS; database=Billing; integrated security=yes"
command.Connection = connection
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT [Customer] FROM [Billing]

For Each... Distinct value returned above

    command.CommandType = CommandType2.Text
    command.CommandText2 = "Select * FROM [Billing] WHERE [Customer] = [DISTINCT VALUE FROM ABOVE]
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command

        'Fill data to datatable
        connection.Open()
        dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain)
        connection.Close()

Then Export (I am ok with the Export code)
```

In essence I need to be able to loop until I have a datatable per customer exported.

Hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that real code? Why do you want to loop every distinct cutomer just to be able to select all Billings for these customers? Wouldn't it be much more efficient to select all billings in the first place? `Select * FROM [Billing] ORDER BY Customer`

Comment: You can just use a self join on Billing table and Group By Customer.

Comment: @PradeepKumar: presumes that he doesn't want all rows of each customer. The inner select speaks against.

Comment: I need a separate output for each customer. So for customer A, I want to export a file with all of Customer A's billing details and for customer B, all of customers B's billing details and so on...

Comment: ok.. In that case, you can just fill the datatable once (`SELECT * FROM Billing ORDER BY Customer`). Then you can filter on each customer and get rows related to that customer. That would be much more efficient than looping and filling data for each customer separately.

Comment: How do I apply a filter, can you provide an example? Will that give me a separate export file for each customer? Thanks

Comment: Your comments imply you are OK with your export code. This simplest thing would be to select ordered data (as suggested) then export your rows and when you hit a new customer in your dataset, create a new file and export to that.

Comment: Yes, though I don't have much time to create sample code at present. Its very easy. This article explains in detail how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: That code isn't doing any exporting. I suggest you don't mess about with sorting and filtering datatables. I suggest you look at stuff like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613539/loop-through-the-rows-of-a-particular-datatable and learn how to use a for each loop to step through your datatable rows. There's probably an even quicker way to do it.

Comment: Presumably I will still have to use a loop? How do I store the SQL select distinct as a variable for the filter?

Comment: Forget about distinct. Simply fill the datatable once with ordered data. Now step through each record, checking the client each time. Every time you get a new client (you'll need a variable to remember the last one), create a new export file.

Comment: Here is some more code that exports a datatable to a text file. Inside the loop you check if the client id has changed at each row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206577/generating-a-txt-file-from-a-datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some untested code. But it will give you a fair idea about what I was talking about (in the comments of question).

```vb
Sub Whatever()
    connection.ConnectionString = "server=***01\SQLEXPRESS; database=Billing; integrated security=yes"
    connection.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Billing] ORDER BY Customer", connection)
        da.Fill(datatableMain)
    End Using
    connection.Close()

    ' get distinct customers
    Dim dv As New DataView(datatableMain)
    Dim distinctCustomers As DataTable = dv.ToTable(True, "Customer")

    For Each customer As DataRow In distinctCustomers.Rows
        ' this messagebox is only to give you an idea which customer you are printing
        ' not required in actual code.
        MessageBox.Show("Exporting Customer... " & customer("Customer").ToString)

        Dim customerRows() As DataRow = datatableMain.Select("Customer=" & customer("Customer").ToString)  '<-- put single quotes around value if "Customer" field is of string type. e.g. "Customer='value'"
        For Each customerRow As DataRow In customerRows
            ' all the rows related to this customer are here
            ' do whatever you do to export

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep, looks good. However it currently errors. Additional information: Cannot find column [ALL001]. ALL001 my first customer value, not a column name? Thanks

Comment: my field is called 'CustomerLookup'. Here is the line that throws the error: Dim customerRows() As DataRow = datatableMain.Select("CustomerLookup=" & customer("CustomerLookup").ToString)

Comment: What happens if you put single quotes around the values. `Dim customerRows() As DataRow = datatableMain.Select("CustomerLookup = '" & customer("CustomerLookup").ToString & "'")`

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep that seems to have done the trick. I will mark this post as answered. Unfortunately my code is now hanging. I have opened a new thread and posted my latest code here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488938/vb-code-to-export-multiple-excel-files-is-hanging Thanks