# VB code to export multiple Excel files is hanging

Tags: vb.net

I am relatively new to vb.net, but have constructed the following code to export from a datatable to multiple Excel files.

Unfortunately the code hangs.

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with my code?

Also any tips on how to troubleshoot these types of issues would be handy.

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Initialize the objects before use
    Dim dataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim dataSet As New DataSet
    Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim datatableMain As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

    connection.ConnectionString = "server=inlt01\SQLEXPRESS; database=DaisyBilling; integrated security=yes"
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    connection.Open()
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [DaisyBilling].[dbo].[" + DaisyBillingForm.TextBox1.Text + "] ORDER BY [CustomerLookup]", connection)
        da.Fill(datatableMain)

        connection.Close()

        Dim f As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        Try
            If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                'This section help you if your language is not English.
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
                Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
                Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
                Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
                oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
                Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
                Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

                Dim dv As New DataView(datatableMain)
                Dim distinctCustomers As System.Data.DataTable = dv.ToTable(True, "CustomerLookup")

                For Each customer As DataRow In distinctCustomers.Rows

                    'MessageBox.Show("Exporting Customer... " & customer("CustomerLookup").ToString)

                    Dim customerRows() As DataRow = datatableMain.Select("CustomerLookup = '" & customer("CustomerLookup").ToString & "'")
                    For Each customerRow As DataRow In customerRows

                        'Export the Columns to excel file
                        For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                            colIndex = colIndex + 1
                            oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                        Next

                        'Export the rows to excel file
                        For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                            colIndex = 0
                            For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                                oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString()

                            Next
                        Next

                        'Set final path

                        Dim fileName As String = "\" + DaisyBillingForm.TextBox1.Text + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".xls"
                        Dim finalPath = f.SelectedPath + fileName
                        'TextBox1.Text = finalPath
                        oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

                        'Save file in final path
                        oBook.SaveAs(finalPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, _
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

                    Next
                Next

                'Release the objects
                ReleaseObject(oSheet)
                oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                ReleaseObject(oBook)
                oExcel.Quit()
                ReleaseObject(oExcel)
                'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: 
                'so i am calling GC.Collect method.
                GC.Collect()

                MessageBox.Show("Export done successfully!")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

When I do a Break All, it shows it hanging on this line of code

oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString()

Comment: Have you considered moving this code into a background/worker thread?

Comment: I just viewed the code and one quick thing I noticed is the position of `End Using`. You should close that as soon as you are done with it. Just as I showed you in the other thread. Move it just after `da.Fill` line. Though this is unlikely to be the cause of problem you are facing.

Comment: You asked for the tip - here it is: Stop doing what you're doing. Use empty excel workbook/sheet as template. Then populate it using 'Microsoft.Ace.Oledb'. Any time you do `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` you can expect the unexpected. We had to process these in a separate domain. But to fill the spread sheet, you don't need it. Besides, Microsoft doesn't support it.

Comment: Ditto. I suggest using Excel to load the data from the database instead of Excel automation. The automation stuff is problematic and not portable. ADO.Net works as well and IMO works better with SQL Server.

Comment: `dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString()` <-- doesn't handle `dbNull`

Answer (score 2):

> any tips on how to troubleshoot these types of issues would be handy.

I'd recommend using tracing and debugging to diagnose issues in your program.

**Tracing**

Use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) to write program status to the output window, e.g. before and after you write each row, before and after you write the Excel file, etc.

**Debugging**

Step through your code in the [debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). Set breakpoints and check that they are reached and the program state (local variables window) is as you expected it.
You can also use Break All from the menu to find what is currently executing if you feel it is stuck.

**Structure**

Consider breaking the code into smaller functions so that you can reason about the code more easily.

> Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with my code?

Are you sure you want to save an Excel file for each customer?

If so perhaps use the customer's name or id for the file name instead of the current time, and consider clearing the Excel sheet after each save.

Long running actions should not be run on the UI thread, consider running this on the thread pool or a background worker thread and showing a [progress bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx).

I suspect that the operation is taking a long time to complete, but as there is no feedback (progress bar etc.) it feels like it is hanging.

Also note that the variable `colIndex` should be set to zero for each iteration, i.e.

```
                For Each customerRow As DataRow In customerRows

                    'Set colIndex to zero here
                    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0

                    'Export the Columns to excel file
                    For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                    Next
```

Comment: If I add the Dim colIndex variable there it errors. Error Variable 'colIndex' hides a variable in an enclosing block. I do set it to zero above - do I need to repeat that? Thanks

Comment: no problem, you don't need to repeat the 'colIndex' variable, simply move it